# Cannot assign regex string in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I'm having issue assigning regex value to a string. Issue that I have is I have \d in the string value and objective-c complaining!

**Here is my code**

I'm assigning regex value here.

```
- (BOOL) validateUSZipCode: (NSString *) candidate {
   NSString *regex = @"^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$"; 
   NSPredicate *test = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex]; 

   return [test evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```

Someone help me please!

Comment: What do you mean by "complaining?"

Comment: it warns me: Unknown escape sequence '\d'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote backslashes to include them in a constant `NSString`.

```
NSString *regex = @"^\\d{5}(-\\d{4})?$";
```